# jQuery UI Sortable Portlets Force right or left

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, portlet

Based off [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4zKp9/) example on jsfiddle, what I have is identical. I'm trying to come up with a way for when you have an empty space on the right and be able to move the left div to the right without being forced back.

I've tried the following css:

```
$(function() 
    if( $(".portlet").css('left', '165px') ) { 
        $(".portlet").css('left', '51%');
    } else {
      $(".portlet").css('left', '1%');
    }
)};
```

Just to note that I'm fairly new to jQuery UI.

Comment: What steps do I have to do on the jsfiddle to see the problem? I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @loli If you try to move a portlet from the left to the right (given that the right is empty) It's forced back to the left.

Comment: doesn't do this for me. What browser you using?

Comment: @loli Testing it on Firefox.

Comment: so what you want is to not have to drop the box on the designated space but anywhere on the right column where it's empty?

Comment: Correct @loli. I haven't found a single example of this though. If it's possible. Just looking for a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to do this, if it doesn't interfere with the rest of your layout, would be to force the height of your sortable. Like this:

```
.sortable {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  height: 600px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g6urafLf/1/